# Translating user id when creating image

Tags: permissions, file-copy

I want to create an image (for example ext3 image) from a given directory hierarchy. This directory hierarchy is owned by a given user. But on the final image, I want the files to be owned by superuser. Is there a solution for tranlating the user uid / gid to 0 ?

Here is a pseudo workflow :

1. Create file hierarchy, as user in `/home/user/rootfs`
2. Create an ext3 img on a file
3. loop mount the empty img (as user or root) in `/somewhere/loopmount`
4. `cp -R --magic_uid_options 500=0 /home/user/rootfs /somewhere/loopmount`

Or step 4 could be a normal copy and step 5 a clever find that would `chown` and `chgrp` recursively. Is there well known solution to this kind of problem ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any "`--magic_uid_options`" for the `cp` command and you don't need to be *clever* for doing recursive `chown` or `chgrp`.

In fact I would:

- keep as much files/directory properties as possible when doing the copy (timestamp, ...)

  ```
  cp -pR /home/users/rootfs /somewhere/loopmount/
  ```
- `chown` all to `root:root`:

  ```
  chown -R root:root /somewhere/loopmount
  ```

Comment: Your absolutely right. Just after asking the question I googled for recursive chown... -R is not that clever indeed ;)

Comment: `man` is also a good thing to start with ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could make step 4, as root:

```
cd /home/user/rootfs
pax -rw -pp . /somewhere/loopmount
```

`-pp` preserves modes and times but creates files owned by the user and group running `pax`.